# JavaScript Find In .TXT File

Tags: javascript

I have exhausted google for a JavaScript "Find In Page" tool to place in a HTML file so that when I enter a search term and click submit, the script will search a TEXT file of my choice and find a match on the text page for the entry submitted.

This is an example of what I'm looking for:

Page A - This is the start page:

http://mobilestimulus.com/tests/field_search/index

Employee enters part# on page A, and Part# is highlighted on page B.

Page B, the page to be searched, is a .txt file. Example:

http://mobilestimulus.com/tests/field_search/file1

I asked this in another thread, but the methods given won't do the trick, and the thread got marked Answed. Can someone give me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: Please do not start duplicate questions just because someone gave an answer in your other question. That question is still open (and continues to be visited by people) until *you* mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: Sorry. Still new to this forum and getting the hang of it...

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood I think you should use your server side language for searching the part#. You can write the code to parse the file and find the part# entered in the first page.
You can not use javascript  to read from a file on server(I suppose if I've followed the question correctly pageB resides on server).

Comment: Yes, file is on Internet. I have access to no programming languages (Free Host Limitations), so JavaScript seems to be my only option... I know it is a bummer....

Comment: Well then if file is on server and you cannot access it via javascript. Still here is a link you can check this http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=647

Comment: Thanks for the info. I do believe what I'm looking for is possible, so I continue to hold out for a solution....